# Wrapping null-returning method in Java with Option in Scala?

Tags: java, scala, scala-option

Suppose I have a method `session.get(str: String): String` but you don't know whether it will return you a string or a null, because it comes from Java.

Is there an easier way to treat this in Scala instead of `session.get("foo") == null` ? Maybe some magic apply like `ToOption(session.get("foo"))` and then I can treat it in Scala way like

```
ToOption(session.get("foo")) match {
    case Some(_) =>;
    case None =>;
}
```

Comment: For more Option tricks see http://blog.tmorris.net/scalaoption-cheat-sheet/

Comment: The link above should be http://blog.tmorris.net/posts/scalaoption-cheat-sheet/.

Answer (score 212, accepted):

The `Option` companion object's `apply` method serves as a conversion function from nullable references:

```
scala> Option(null)
res4: Option[Null] = None

scala> Option(3)   
res5: Option[Int] = Some(3)
```

Answer (score 20):

The `Option` object has an `apply`method that does exactly that:

```
var myOptionalString = Option(session.get("foo"));
```

Answer (score 5):

Notice that when working with Java objects it won't work as expected:

```
val nullValueInteger : java.lang.Integer = null
val option: Option[Int] = Option(nullValueInteger)
println(option)  // Doesn't work - zero value on conversion

val nullStringValue : String = null
val optionString: Option[String] = Option(nullStringValue)
println(optionString) // Works - None value
```

Comment: I ran with scala 2.11.8. The second line throwed NullPointerException.  The sixth line got Some(null), not None as you expected.

Comment: 1. Used Some instead of Option in optionString - Changed in original answer.
2. Verified only in Scala 2.12.5

Answer (score -1):

This is a very old topic but a nice one!

It's true that converting any Non-exception result of Try to Option will result in a Some...

```scala
scala> Try(null).toOption
res10: Option[Null] = Some(null)
```

...because Try is not about nullability checking but just a way to functionally handle exceptions.

Using Try to catch an exception and converting that to an Option for convenience will only show None in case an exception happens.

```scala
scala> Try(1/0).toOption
res11: Option[Int] = None
```

You want to preserve the values that come out of Try. That may be null.

But it is also true that the standard lib is quite confusing sometimes...

```scala
scala> Try(null).toOption
res12: Option[Null] = Some(null)

scala> Option(null)
res13: Option[Null] = None
```

This behaviour is a bit inconsistent but it kind of reflects the intented usage of both Try and Option.

You use try to get whatever comes out of an expression that may throw exceptions, and you don't care about the exception itself.

The value that may come out may very well be a null. If toOption gave None, **you could not differenciate between an exception and a null**, and that is not pretty!

Standalone, you use Option to encapsulate the existence or not of something. So in that case Some(null) is None, and that makes sense, because null in that case represents the absence of something. There's no ambiguity here.

It's important to remark that in any case referencial transparency is not broken since .toOption is **not** the same as Option()

If you really need to enforce **BOTH** exception safety **AND** null safety, and your code *really really doesn't need to differenciate between null and an exception*, you just need to combine both paradigms! Because well, that's what you want, right?

You can do it in one way...

```scala
scala> Try(Option(null)).getOrElse(None)
res23: Option[Null] = None

scala> Try(Option(3/0)).getOrElse(None)
res24: Option[Int] = None

scala> Try(Option(3)).getOrElse(None)
res25: Option[Int] = Some(3)
```

... or another ...

```scala
scala> Try(Option(null)).toOption.flatten
res26: Option[Null] = None

scala> Try(Option(3/0)).toOption.flatten
res27: Option[Int] = None

scala> Try(Option(3)).toOption.flatten
res28: Option[Int] = Some(3)
```

... or the ridiculously ugliest of them anothers ...

```scala
scala> Option(Try(null).getOrElse(null))
res29: Option[Null] = None

scala> Option(Try(3/0).getOrElse(null))
res30: Option[Any] = None

scala> Option(Try(3).getOrElse(null))
res31: Option[Any] = Some(3)
```