# Is there a way of creating an std::optional<> out of a nullable argument?

Tags: c++, stdoptional

Languages such as Scala and Java have had for quite some time some sort of optional type. In both, there seems to be a constructor method allowing one to either pass in an object `O` or a null value. The first constructs an optional value with a copy of `O` inside it, the second, an empty option.

From what I can gather, such a thing is not possible with `std::optional<>(v)` and `std::make_optional<>(v)`, as both throw a runtime exception when called with a `nullptr` argument.

Is there any other constructor function allowing me to do this in the standard library?

Thanks

Comment: `std::optional` stores an object (optionally) not a pointer.

Comment: Sounds like you are looking for `std::nullopt`

Comment: @Scheff'sCat My question is not how to create an empty optional -- it's how to create an optional value out of a possibly nullable argument.

Comment: what is a "possibly nullable argument" ? The "null" for `std::optional` is not `nullptr` but `nullopt`

Comment: @It's perfectly fine once the value type allows initialization from `nullptr`. Such as `auto os = std::make_optional<std::unique_ptr<int>>(nullptr);`. Live demo: https://godbolt.org/z/rh3GsGa4c.

Comment: @DanielLangr that code in gcc with C++ 20 throws a runtime exception.

Comment: @devouredelysium Sorry, we cannot create a `std::string` from `nullptr`. Corrected.

Comment: Can you add some desired behavior to your question?  That should help us understand a little better what you want, since C++ doesn't really have nullable objects.  All objects in C++ have a value.  Even a null pointer has a value of `0`, and that is treated as a special pointer value.

Comment: Not every object in C++ is "nullable". Based on the behavior you're requesting, I'd argue that every `std::optional<T>` is nullable, and that null value is `std::nullopt`.

If you want all of your variables in C++ to be "nullable", then use `std::optional<T>` for all of them.

Comment: Other options to make your things universally nullable are to use `std::shared_ptr<T>` for everything, as that has a nullable concept (empty `std::shared_ptr<T>`), or for every return type where you care about the nullable property, define in your own application space a special value that counts as null, and check for that every time you care. These are crazy though.

When I write a function that may or may not return a usable value, I use nullptrs if the function would normally return a pointer type, or I use std::optional otherwise. Those two combined get me all I need.

Comment: Can you explain *why* you need to use `nullptr`? Why `std::nullopt` doesn't work for you? `std::nullopt` is a canonical way to return an empty `std::optional`.

Comment: If the construction of the type in question accepts a null pointer to begin with, it should either work fine or not compile. Please post a [mcve].

Comment: In C++, `std::optional` has a constructor method allowing one to either pass in an object `O` or a `std::nullopt` value.  Very similar to Scala and Java.

Comment: @Eljay if one has a `std::optional<T> foo` where `T` can be initialized with a `nullptr`, I'd assume that `if (foo)` and `if(foo.value() == nullptr)` *should* signal different things. Otherwise, there's no reason to have the `std::optional`. `nullptr` here then doesn't signal the "nullable" version of `std::optional<T>`. It's still only `std::nullopt`.

Comment: The comment is too old now, and I can't edit it. Only delete. I actually did mean to @molbdnilo

Comment: Note that the only "nullable" types in C++ are pointers (unless you also count the null optional). Types that accept a pointer as a construction argument may throw if that argument is the null pointer. Java's concept of converting null references to the empty optional does not make sense in C++.

Comment: Java terminology and C++ terminology differ on the semantics of *references*.  Java references(Java terminology) are pointers(C++ terminology), and that implementation detail can still be seen in Java's `NullPointerException`.  Historical footnote: Scala was released in 2004.  C++ had Boost Optional in 2003.

Answer (score 4):

Since you didn't showed any code example, I will assume the following:

- You have a function called `f`
- The function `f` takes a potentially null `int*` as parameter (the nullable argument)
- The function `f` returns a `std::optional<int>`
- I will assume you have a similar function body in your codebase

Edit your question to add a more relevant examples if my assumptions are wrong.

---

So to recap the code example:

```
auto f(int* ptr) -> std::optional<int> {
    return std::optional<int>{*ptr};
}
```

The problem don't lie in `std::optional` and its contructors, but in the fact that you dereference a null pointer. This happen before any constructor call. At this point, you're already in UB land, you cannot infer behaviour after this happens.

The fix is to check the pointer before constructing the optional value:

```
auto f(int* ptr) -> std::optional<int> {
    return ptr ? std::optional<int>{*ptr} : std::nullopt;
}
```

Now, the int you send to the `std::optional` constructor is always valid assuming `ptr` is valid or null, and you return an empty optional if not.

Answer (score 2):

An important property of `std::optional` is to not involve dynamic allocations. The object is (optionally) stored directly in the `std::optional`.

A `std::optional<T>` cannot hold a `nullptr` when `T` cannot have a `nullptr` value.

A `std::optional` can be constructed empty by calling the appropriate [constructor](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/optional/optional):

```
// either
std::optional<int> x;                // does not contain an int
// or 
std::optional<int> y{std::nullopt};  // does not contain an int
```

Comment: Hi. That's not what I asked. Please look at https://stackoverflow.com/a/4692607/130758.

Comment: @devouredelysium meanwhile I understood that this is not what you asked, but I dont understand what you do ask. Please clarify the question. In Java, anything can be `null` but not in C++, hence your analogy is not sufficient to know what you are looking for

Comment: @devouredelysium I have no understanding of that language. Can you create a small C++ example that will do what this is supposed to do? Or at least an example that triggers the error you're experiencing?

Answer (score 2):

Maybe you want [std::nullopt](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/optional/nullopt), it signifies that optional doesn't hold value, in other words optional + nullopt is exactly what null means in other lanugages. In other words std::optional + std::nullopt inroduce natural sence of null into C++, same as in other languages.

Through `std::nullopt` you can control optional arguments in the function, like I did below for `add()` function.

You just check `if (optional_value)` to find out if it holds value, which is same as `if (optional_value.has_value())`. See [doc here](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/optional/operator_bool).

Also you can use [.value_or(default)](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/optional/value_or) to return value or default, it is same as saying `var or default` or `var if var is not None else default` in Python for None-able argument.

You can also get value of optional just by `*optional_value` dereference, same like pointer. [Doc here](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/optional/operator*).

See all 4 possibilities of using nullable optional in implementation of `add()` function, it has 4 ways of doing same thing, choose which is better for you.

[Try it online!](https://godbolt.org/z/eeo6b5cE8)

```cpp
#include <optional>
#include <iostream>

int add(int x, std::optional<int> y = std::nullopt) {
    return x + y.value_or(5);
    // also possible to do same like this
    return x + (y ? y.value() : 5);
    // or same as
    return x + (y ? *y : 5);
    // or same as
    if (y)
        return x + *y;
    else
        return x + 5;
}

int main() {
    std::cout << add(3) << std::endl;
    std::cout << add(3, std::nullopt) << std::endl;
    std::cout << add(3, 7) << std::endl;
}
```

Output:

```
8
8
10
```

In other words if you want any variable to hold both value of some type and also null, then just wrap it into std::optional, and use std::nullopt to signify null, like in following example:

```
SomeClass obj; // non-nullable, can't be null
std::optional<SomeClass> obj2; // almost same as above but now is nullable
obj2 = obj; // you can naturally assign value of object
obj2 = std::nullopt; // this way you set variable to null
obj = *obj2; // this way you get value of object by using * dereference
obj = obj2.value(); // same as above instead of *
obj = obj2 ? *obj2 : default_value; // this way you check if obj2 is null, if not then get it's value through *, otherwise return default
obj = obj2.value_or(default_value); // same as last line above
if (obj2) DoSomething(); // checks if object is not null
if (obj2.has_value()) DoSomething(); // same as above
```

See [all docs](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/optional) about std::optional.